# How to create a static body with b2PolygonShape vertices

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I can´t seem to create a b2PolygonShape with vertices in my Box2D Cocos2D project. I get no errors but nothing shows up at the screen.

How do you get a static body with b2PolygonShape vertices to work?

I would like to use it with a list set up like this:

```
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
        b2Vec2(-194.5f / PTM_RATIO, 83.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(-118.5f / PTM_RATIO, 65.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(-77.5f / PTM_RATIO, 2.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(3.5f / PTM_RATIO, -59.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(62.5f / PTM_RATIO, -61.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(108.5f / PTM_RATIO, -63.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(138.5f / PTM_RATIO, -41.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(169.5f / PTM_RATIO, 11.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(184.5f / PTM_RATIO, 49.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(218.5f / PTM_RATIO, 51.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(219.5f / PTM_RATIO, -89.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(-174.5f / PTM_RATIO, -88.0f / PTM_RATIO)
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next step will specifying the vertices to shape

```
     b2PolygonShape shape;
        int num = 4;
        b2Vec2 vertices[] = {
                    b2Vec2(10.5f / PTM_RATIO, 10.6f / PTM_RATIO),
                    b2Vec2(11.8f / PTM_RATIO, 18.1f / PTM_RATIO),
                    b2Vec2(-11.9f / PTM_RATIO, 18.3f / PTM_RATIO),
                    b2Vec2(-10.5f / PTM_RATIO, 10.8f / PTM_RATIO)
                };
        shape.Set(vertices, num);
```

`b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;`